# Details on kriging and variograms

Tags: variogram, geostatistics, kriging

I was wondering what are the steps to perform factoring kriging. I know it is used to extract specific components that may have a physical meaning and this is achieved by kriging. However, I have some questions regarding the specifics of such procedure. By the way, the following description of the problem belongs to Wackernagel's excellent book [Multivariate Geostatistics](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/3540441425).

Suppose we have a random variable $Z({\bf{x}})$ that can be decomposed into some stationary components $Z_{u}({\bf{x}_{\alpha}})$ and an intrinsic component $Z_{S}({\bf{x_{\alpha}}})$. We are interested in kriging this intrinsic component: $Z_{S}^{*}({\bf{x_{0}}}) = \sum_{\alpha=1}^{n}w_{\alpha}^{S}Z({\bf{x_{\alpha}}})$

Therefore, estimating the variance $\sigma_{E}^{2}$ we get:

\begin{array}{}
\sigma_{E}^{2} &= var(Z_{S}^{*}({\bf{x_{0}}})-Z_{S}({\bf{x_{0}}}))\\
& = \sum_{u=0}^{S-1}C^{u}({\bf{x_0}}-{\bf{x_0}}) - \gamma^{S}({\bf{x_0}}-{\bf{x_0}}) - \sum_{\alpha=1}^{n}\sum_{\beta=1}^{n}w_{\alpha}^{S}w_{\beta}^{S}\gamma({\bf{x_\alpha}}-{\bf{x_\beta}})\\
&+2\sum_{\alpha=1}^{n}w_{\alpha}^{S}\gamma^{S}({\bf{x_\alpha}}-{\bf{x_0}})
\end{array}

and minimizing (with respect to the weights) we obtain:

$$\sum_{\beta=1}^{n} w_{\beta}^{S}\gamma({\bf{x_\alpha}}-{\bf{x_\beta}}) + \mu_{S} = \gamma^{S}({\bf{x_\alpha}}-{\bf{x_0}}) \thinspace \thinspace \text{for $\alpha$=1,...n}$$

$$\sum_{\beta=1}^{n}w_{\beta}^{S}=1$$

where $\mu_{S}$ is the Lagrange multiplier due to the constraint on the weights.

As I understand it, the idea usually is to get the weights $w_{\beta}$ that minimize the variance $\sigma_{E}^{2}$ in order to estimate new values ${\bf{x_{0}}}$. In this case, the values to be estimated are the intrinsic components $Z_{S}^{*}({\bf{x_{0}}})$. However, I'm not sure how to fit from data the variograms needed for these equations.

Furthermore, in factoring kriging the variogram or covariance function is decomposed into several variograms that correspond to the components of $Z({\bf{x}})$. Assuming I know the variograms, should I use something like $\gamma_{1}({\bf{x_\alpha}}-{\bf{x_\beta}}) + \gamma_{2}({\bf{x_\alpha}}-{\bf{x_\beta}}) ... $ in place of $\gamma({\bf{x_\alpha}}-{\bf{x_\beta}})$ in the kriging equations?

Comment: Variogram fitting *usually* requires human intervention. After you find the variogram models that best describe your data, add them together with appropriate "normalization constants". This is often done to capture variability at different lag scales.

Comment: Thank you. Then the chosen components must be fitted _manually_ and used independently in the kriging equations in order to obtain the weights?